# how cal i call a function from clicking in the other page?

Tags: php, css, html, codeigniter-3

i want to call the `default_cat()` for another process, but i want it by clicking the anchor from the other page?

```
<a href="example.com/menu2/('default_cat()')">VIEW DETAILS &#x226B</a>
```

but not working.

```
function default_cat() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url();?>menu2/prod_category/1',
        method: "post",
        success: function(data){
            $(".tab-panes").html(data);
            $("#menu-text-a").focus();
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work, is because of security concerns. The correct way to do this is to have the function on your first page.

Comment: is their any other way sir?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why you would want to call a function from another page.

Comment: Alternative method is there

Comment: what is the other alternative way sir without using the document.reacy(function) just the call it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381160/jquery-run-a-function-from-another-page