# jQuery If url window.location.pathname ends with #&ui-page=

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm manipulating a nested list in jquery mobile. I need to run a check if the url ends with x#&ui-page=globalMenu-"and a number". How can I do this?

ex for a url

```
www.test.no/Site/default.aspxx#&ui-page=globalMenu-7
```

I want to check if the site ends/contains #&ui-page=globalMenu

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery URL Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113397/jquery-url-hash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(location.hash.indexOf('&ui-page=globalMenu') != -1){
   //It ends with #&ui-page=
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.hash` will give you access to `#&ui-page=globalMenu-7`.

So the following code will do what you want:

```
var matches = window.location.hash.match(/#\&ui-page=globalMenu\-([0-9])?/);
```

For the example you give:

`matches[0]` will contain: `#&ui-page=globalMenu-7`

and `matches[1]` will contain: `7`

Comment: Just a question.. what if the last number can go up to 1000?

Comment: The last number can be pretty much any number. It just looks for one or more digits which are 0-9.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the value of `window.location.hash` for equality with your desired string.

**Example:**

Url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929224/jquery-if-url-window-location-pathname-ends-with-ui-page/8929249#8929249`

Value of `window.location.hash`: `#8929249`

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `window.location.hash` will give you then hash of your url.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(/#&ui-page=globalMenu-[0-9]+/.test(location.hash))
     {
         // do stuff
     }
```