# how to pass an object through url in javascript as a single var

Tags: jquery, url, object

how to pass a js object through url

i have a js object

```
var info = {
    status: 1 ,
    time: "10:00:00-12:00:00" ,
    weekdays: {
      "monday",
      "tuesday"
    }
};
```

i **don't want to use serialize**, i want something like **"localhost/jstest/#test?info"**

Is there any way i can achieve this

Comment: will your object have second level?for example object{ p : "value" , p2 : value , p3 : {pi1 : value , pi2 : value} }

Comment: but weekdays looks more like an array than object.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399749/embedding-javascript-objects-in-a-pages-url/15399819#15399819

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are going to have to serialize it one way or another. You could do it in the way you suggest by storing a JSON string representing your object in e.g. [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage), and passing the name of the key:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("info", JSON.stringify(info));
window.location("localhost/jstest/#test?info");
```

You can then access the data stored in that key:

```
var info = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("info"));
```

Comment: It won't work in IE below 8. But if you care about older browsers you could use a cookie instead, or use a [web storage polyfill](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/).

Comment: i will have to care about older browsers

Comment: Then use a cookie or the polyfill that I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own querystring with the hashtag, then get the data from the url/hashtag in your code to retrieve the data.

like this:

`localhost/jstest/#info!status=1!time=10:00:00-12:00:00!weekdays=monday,tuesday`

Then you can find more help on how to read the hashtag data here: [Working with single page websites and maintaining state using a URL hash and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113397/jquery-url-hash)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.
Here you convert your object to JSON first, after making that string safe with base64 encoding for use in URL.
Note this uses an additional plugin `jquery.base64.js` for working with base64. You can use your own library.

```js
function packer(o){
    var str = JSON.stringify(a);
    var mess = $.base64.encode(str);
    return mess.replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/=/g,',');
}
function unpacker(str){
    var mess  = str.replace(/-/g,'+').replace(/_/g,'/').replace(/,/g,'=');
    mess = $.base64.decode(mess);
    return JSON.parse(mess);
}
```